# Как сделать возможным использование и точки, и запятой как разделителя дробной части?

Tags: c, visual-c++, локализация

При включенном setlocale ввод десятичной дроби возможен только с точкой,при вводе с запятой - программа входит в бесконечный цикл. Как сделать корректной ввод дроби с запятой?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

main()
{
    int counter = 0, distance;
    float consumption, average, total = 0;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    printf("Введите расход бензина (-1, если ввод закончен): ");
    scanf("%f", &consumption);

    while (consumption != -1)
    {
        printf("Введите пройденный путь: ");
        scanf("%d", &distance);
        printf("Для этой заправки получено миль/галлон %f"), (float)distance / consumption;
        total += (float)distance / consumption;
        counter++;
        printf("\n\nВведите расход бензина (-1, если ввод закончен): ");
        scanf("%f", &consumption);
    }

    if (counter != 0)
    {
        average = (float) total / counter;
        printf("\nСреднее число миль/галлон %f\n", average);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Ни одного значения не было введено\n");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

Comment: читайте как строку, а потом исправляйте разделитель на удобный Вам. И потом уже переводите в число.

Comment: Первый параметр отвечает за категорию на которую влияет локаль(денежная, временная, и в т.ч. разделитель в плавающих числах) Если вам необходим только вывод кириллицы можно использовать `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian")`.[setlocale](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/setlocale/), [setlocale.ru](http://cppstudio.com/post/1044/)