# c++, Чем отличается запятая от точки в double и float?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Всем привет) Я новичок в с++, пытаюсь сам разобраться, потому что в универе ничему не учат, но да ладно. Недавно решая лабу, столкнулся с таким животрепещущим для меня вопросом, а именно, в чем же различие 0.5 и 0,5 для с++ ??? В чем та самая разница? Приведу пример: задание2 Определить количество положительных чисел среди чисел a, b и c. Простое задание, мой код представлен на первой картинке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Все вроде хорошо идет, код работает как молоток, вычисляет отрицательные и положительные числа (то есть целые), но проблемы начинаются с дробно-рациональными числами. Когда я пытаюсь ввести 0.5, то все - конец[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Я не могу дальше ничего вводить ( я не понимаю почему), хотя в scanf_s я потребовал ввести 3 переменных, а физически ввести я могу только одну. Когда я ввожу немного другое число - 0,5[image: введите сюда описание изображения], то все работает просто прекрасно, как видно на картинке 2, я ввел три положительных, но рациональных числа с запятой! именно с запятой, НЕ точкой и все работает. Почему так? Почему с++ так не нравится точка? Или это у меня код дурацкий?)

Comment: scanf учитывает формат текущей локали, а так как у вас винда русская, то и локаль в ней русская, а в России в качестве разделителя используется именно запятая

Comment: Серьезно? понял спасибо!

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как сделать возможным использование и точки, и запятой как разделителя дробной части?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/866120)

Comment: @andreymal Дело не в русской винде, автор руками меняет локаль.

Comment: 1) не стоит постить код в виде картинок 2) не стоит ставить теги языков, не относящихся к проблеме 3) следует читать документацию к каждой используемой функции начиная с https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale